# java populate beans from JDBCtemplate

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

Hi I have a query which returns about 600-700K rows into a result set.  Once this happens we are using the BeanPropertyRowMapper to populate these beans.  This part takes for ever.  Is there a faster way to do this.  I also tried RowMapper thinking that by calling the setters in the bean it would be faster but will this speed anything up.  And if not is there a better way?

Comment: Do you really need all those 600k+ objects in memory simultaneously? You might want to look for better solution

Comment: yes.  We need to read from DB and write to file.  At this time we have to do it this way as the base code is doing it this way

Comment: Can't you just write directly to file while you parse the result set?

Comment: Don't read all the rows and don't convert them all to objects. Simply use a RowCallbackHandler do directly stream them to file.

Comment: Cant do that the way the framework we are extending goes like this get rows from columns --> create beans--> save beans to different DB --> write to file

Comment: *Profile* the application to find out whether the overhead is in the `BeanPropertyRowMapper` (which I doubt) or in the network overhead of the database call.

Comment: The issue was the beanPropertyRowMapper. I changed the code to use threads to process the resultSet.  Still in work will update how that works

Answer (score 1):

The BeanPropertyRowMapper is actually useful for its convenience rather than performance. The row mapper actually uses the BeanWrapper in its heart to map the row. and It gives a usual trade-off between performance and flexibility.

Implementing your own RowMapper will definitely be faster in this case (as long as you dont use BeanWrapper to map the row to object). In one of my old project this improvement is quite significant (on 89000 entries from 4 hours using BeanWrapper variant to less than 1 hour by implementing my own custom RowMapper)